# ng-model does not recalculate length of array on single keypress for a textfilter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I've got a table which uses a filtered textarea to construct a filtered table and list a count. The DOM is as follows.

```
 <div filter-input></div>

 <table>
    <tr ng-repeat='item in filtered=(mySourceJSON | filter:filterInputService.searchText)'></tr>
    .. .. ..
    .. .. ..
 </table>
```

With filter input being a directive:

```
angular.module('myApp')
.directive('filterInput', function () {
return {
  controller: 'FilterInputCtrl',
  templateUrl: 'views/filter_input.html',
  restrict: 'A',
  link: function(scope, el, attr){
  }
};
```

});

With the following controller:

```
angular.module('myApp')
 .controller('FilterInputCtrl', function ($scope, filterInputService) {
   $scope.filterInputService = filterInputService;
});
```

And the contents of the template being:

```
 <div>
   <span>
    <input  ng-model='filterInputService.searchText'/>
   </span>
   <span>
      Showing {{filtered.length}} / {{gridItems.length}}
   </span>
 </div>
```

The service is a simple placeholder which sets searchText to `empty string` at initialization.

The behaviour I'm seeing is as follows:

When I type a character into the filter input, the table updates and hides the items that do not match the filter, however, the count of filtered items does not update until a second character is entered. What exactly is triggering this? Why does the scope not update until the second character? How can this be avoided?

Comment: There seems to have no problem with your code. It should work normally. Take a look at this [Plnker](http://plnkr.co/edit/P5wUbxrUvFvqsZLBhMpi?p=preview). Maybe you using more than one scope, aren't you?

Comment: The plunker actually exhibits the same behaviour. If you type a single character into the search field, the count incorrectly remains at 3. Could it be something weird with keyUp vs change? EG. Through poking at my code, I believe the filter is lagging by one keypress.

Comment: Put a `console.log` in your FilterInputCtrl function and see how many times it shows up in your console. More than once indicates you could have multiple scoping problems. How many times does `ng-app` appear in your HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, you've hit a bug. I was taking a look at it and it's related to a problem in the digest cycle, but it doesn't seem to be very simple to solve and unstable version already solves it (open the [Plnker](http://plnkr.co/edit/GJ6HrV93JeKclPS8YDJc?p=preview) and change Angular version to `1.1.5` to see).

So I guess you best choice is to work around it as it probably doesn't worth the effort solving this bug for your specific necessity. Currently, you're setting `filtered` through `ng-repeat`. All you got to do is to `$watch` the filter and apply the filter yourself.

Basically:

Change your bind to:

```html
<tr ng-repeat='item in filtered'>
```

Then, in your controller, inject the [`$filter`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter%3afilter) service and store a reference to the collection filter. `$watch` the filter chars and create the `filtered` array:

```js
.controller('FilterInputCtrl', function ($scope, $filter, filterInputService) {
  var dfFilter = $filter('filter');

  $scope.filterInputService = filterInputService;

  $scope.$watch('filterInputService.searchText', function(value) {
    $scope.filtered = dfFilter($scope.mySourceJSON, value);
  });
});
```

Here is a working [Plnker](http://plnkr.co/edit/GJ6HrV93JeKclPS8YDJc?p=preview).